# grafana - data transformation from journald

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

I would like to clean up the data gathered by promtail. Specifically, I want grafana log dashboard to show only show SYSLOG_TIMESTAMP and MESSAGE fields. The problem is that grafana transform doesn't show fields that are otherwise detected by it. The query I'm using is simple - `{name="promtailtest1"}`. Any ideas where to start looking?

Detected fields by grafana transform:
[image: grafana transform]

Detected fields by grafana:

```
Log labels
job systemd-journal
name1   promtailtest1

Detected fields
MESSAGE "1"
PRIORITY    "5"
SYSLOG_FACILITY "1"
SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER   "promtailtest1"
SYSLOG_TIMESTAMP    "Mar  1 11:15:25 "
_BOOT_ID    "d5f4b43026124bccb1372918ff44fb70"
_GID    "1000"
_HOSTNAME   "pc"
_MACHINE_ID "cce4800beb84473b9cd93f8d6412880a"
_PID    "1902474"
_SELINUX_CONTEXT    "unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023"
_SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP  "1646126125653980"
_TRANSPORT  "syslog"
_UID    "1000"
ts  2022-03-01T09:15:25.654Z
tsNs    1646126125654005000
```

Comment: I don't understand Q. How does "I want grafana log dashboard to show only show SYSLOG_TIMESTAMP and MESSAGE fields." relate to "The problem is that grafana transform doesn't show fields that are otherwise detected by it." Seems to me Grafana is showing all the fields. Isn't your problem Grafana is showing too many fields?